# How many qubits are required to break classical Diffie-Hellman?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, discrete-logarithm, quantum-cryptanalysis

There have been comparisons between RSA and ECDH with regards to the number of qubits  required to break the algorithm with a specific key size. But how many qubits are required to break "classical" Diffie-Hellman (DH) over a multiplicative (finite, cyclic) group?

This would for instance be interesting for stored DHE TLS sessions that used for key agreement. Would it do better or worse than RSA with a similar key size (and therefore, approximately the same classical cryptographic strength)?

Comment: Actually, it's $4 \cdot x + O(1)$, but I don't have a reference (and sorry for my incorrect comment earlier, I miscounted)